# How can I sync prices after deprecation of presentmentprices field after shopify's 2022-01 API release

Tags: synchronization, shopify, shopify-api

Shopify is deprecating some fields after their new release. [deprecations](https://shopify.dev/api/release-notes/2022-01#graphql-storefront-api-changes)
Their docs suggest we should move towards [internationalization](https://shopify.dev/api/examples/international-pricing).

But this shift towards internationalization is a bit confusing to support in my database.
The main reason being, that the [GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/api/examples/international-pricing#example) expects a country code as the context variable, and if I fetch a list of available countries, I get a complete list of countries with USD as the default currency of all these countries.

Now the main issue that I am facing is that, I will have to request prices per Product/ProductVariant per country, which will:

A: take forever to sync, plus a lot of throttling issues will also occur
B: My database will be filled with redundant and default data.

I can probably check for USD as a default country and see the primary currency of a country should be or should not be USD, to skip a lot of these countries, but this doesnt feel like a solid approach. Am I missing some other API which will help me filter the list of countries to those countries only, that are actually supported by a store.

If there are other better approaches to sync prices with shopify, I am all ears.

Comment: Please share the approach you end up using! I too keep a price in my DB that is used for store sales and it is utterly and completely confusing as to how I should handle saving a price. To me, in my database, it is a BigDecimal. End of story, but on the Shopify, it has to be localized! That is so hard to translate into code!